# Statistical Analysis of Runtime Measurements of a Parallel Algorithm

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, statistics, runtime, measurement

#### Problem Introduction

Assume we have a parallel algorithm `f(<params>)` running on `P` cores whereas

- `<params>`: Parameters for algorithm
- `P`: Number of cores it runs on (i.e. threads, cores, processors)

We further assume that out implementation actually consists of three parts:

- A - Distribution: We distribute the input to all processors
- B - Run the algorithm: We run `f(<params>)` ("on each processor")
- C - Collection: We collect the computed data from all processors

After fixing `<params>` and `P` like input size, number of processors etc. the algorithm itself is deterministic i.e. we can write down an exact cDAG for it.

I'm now trying to answer the question: "For a given set of parameters, what is the execution time for a given system?"

With "given system" I mean e.g. "my computer" or "the university super computer" because obviously, the runtime does depend on the system it runs on and obviously the system itself does introduce non-determinism because you never really know the state of the system.

So in short: While the algorithm might be deterministic, runtime measurements aren't. (but e.g. communication measurements would be deterministic.) So we need to do a proper statistical analysis. And this is where I'm unsure.

#### Measuring Runtime: Basic idea

We are interested in how long part "B - Run the Algorithm" takes. Since the algorithm actually runs on `P` cores we'll make a measurement on each core and so get `P` values, let call those `P` values `P_measurements`. Some cores might finish before others, so which value does represent the runtime of the whole algorithm? I think a good choice is to simply take value of the core that took the longest i.e. `max(P_measurements)`.

Now there are two things that need consideration here:

1. We have to repeat the measurement `n` times since it's a non-deterministic value
2. Once we have those `n*P` values, we need to know how to properly summarize them.

(And additional concern would be how to communicate those results in the end, but that's not part of this question.)

#### Measuring Runtime: Statistical Analysis

So here's what I'd do and this is also the part where I'm very unsure.

1. We measure the runtime of `f(<params>)` on each of the `P` cores. We get `P_measurements`
2. We take `max(P_measurements)`
3. We repeat 1. & 2. `n` times and we end up with `maxes`. Whereas `maxes` is a list of the `n` values `max(P_measurements)`
4. We check if `maxes`is normally distributed using a Q-Q-Plot. If not, we normalize. We do expect it to be right-skewed.
5. Now we take the median of `maxes`. (If we normalized, we use the normalized values)
6. We compute the standard deviation, the population mean and the 95% confidence interval.
7. We might want to say that all values are of an error of e.g. 5% so we check if all the values lie between +-5% of the population mean i.e. the confidence interval should be rather "thin".
8. We got ourselves some nice runtime measurement.

Clarifications:
Step 4. was necessary because computing the CI in step 6 uses the t-distribution and because later on I want to measure a different implementation of the same algorithm. So I'll have to compare two values and for that I need to do e.g. a t-test. So I need to make sure, the prerequisites for the t-test are met, which are: iid & normally distributed. Iid is assumed.

#### Question

I am very unsure what I did is statistically sound. Especially step 1-3. I'm not sure if I can do that kind of summarization (just take the max) here. I know that we might have an outsider value that's "especially" high but since we only measure on super computers we can assume the noise to be low and since we take the median in the end any outliners shouldn't have a big impact.

I hope for good input since it's a rather complex topic and I'm very interested in doing it right. I mostly followed the following paper, which I can recommend: http://spcl.inf.ethz.ch/Teaching/2020-dphpc/hoefler-scientific-benchmarking.pdf

But even with the paper, I'm not used to use statistical analysis and thus would just like to get some input from people who actually know this stuff. :)

Comment: There's no problem on collecting whatever amount of DATA on either of the platforms, yet each interpretation has a principal duty to question, whether the each deployment ecosystem remains principally coherent or not with any other. On what grounds do you build your expectation, that all the kinds of (seen & hidden sources of) noise in observations in localhost-ecosystem are the very same as in the target-ecosystem? If they are not coherent, then any statistical re-representation of no matter how many obeservations in a non-coherent ecosystem yield an unconclusive model for other than a former

Comment: 1. I have no idea what you mean by ecosystem. 2. I guess with "localhost-ecosystem" you mean a normal enduser computer? If so: Those are way nosier than a super computer since your computer does everything all the time while on a super computer a node is always dedicated to one task. Also there is no point on running the algorithm on such a small system as your home computer. That's not the goal anyway. If I compute something, then I compare two algorithms (e.g. the state-of-the-art vs. my implementation) and I might do that on different large systems. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Working on a field of interest or in a research group on a topic special to academia or what is the work you plan to complete? HPC infrastructures are (always 've been) rather unique originals.Human knowledge makes The Difference - between days of computing v/s 12 minutes run-times, if due know-how gets harnessed in due time & fashion. A runtime variance is more a subject to introspection what has caused it to appear than a topic to be covered by descriptive statistics ("confidentiality interval",IQR abstraction) the more if your HPC-production has to meet deadlines (like climate/wether SIMs)